# Extracting lazy loaded content using Selenium?

Tags: r, selenium, lazy-loading, browser-automation, rselenium

I'm using selenium to

- navigate to a url
- scroll down (so lazyloaded images load)

When a human watches the automated browser, the resulting HTML **does** contain the lazy loaded content, but when the browser is not on screen, the lazyloaded content **isn't present** in the HTML.

#### Notes

- If I watch the browser while the automated browser is working (i.e. have chrome visible on my laptop screen) then the resulting HTML **does** contain the lazyloaded content
- If the browser is not open on screen (e.g. if I look at something else, like the code executing in the terminal), then the lazyloaded content is **not** contained in the HTML!

#### Question

When a human 'looks' at the browser, the lazyloaded data is captured in the extract HTML, but when the same is done programatically, the lazyloaded data is missing. How come?

#### R Code

```
library(RSelenium)
library(dplyr)


url %>% remDr$navigate(.)
 
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")


for(i in 1:50) { webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "down_arrow")); Sys.sleep(0.02) } # Scroll down
webElem$click(buttonId = 0); Sys.sleep(0.02) # Click on page

# Repeats above scroll/click 4 more times to get to very bottom of page


# Get html
remDr$getPageSource() %>% .[[1]] %>% .[1] %>% read_html(.)
```

Comment: can you provide the link?